# CopyFileEx Won't write metadata on large file (Delayed Write Failure)

Tags: c#

I am using CopyFileEx pinvoke in c# to copy small and large files from a secondary drive to a flash drive. The files in question are MP4 files. The smaller files copy fine however the larger files around 1GB or more, copy the size of the file, but don't include the metadata which makes the MP4 non-playable. What can cause this providing that I've done this right?

After closing the program Windows will tell me there is a delayed write failure.

```
public class XCopy
{
    #region DLL Imports
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool CopyFileEx(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName, CopyProgressRoutine lpProgressRoutine, IntPtr lpData, ref int pbCancel, CopyFileFlags dwCopyFlags);
    #endregion


    #region Delegates
    private delegate CopyProgressResult CopyProgressRoutine(long TotalFileSize, long TotalBytesTransferred, long StreamSize, 
        long StreamBytesTransferred, uint dwStreamNumber, CopyProgressCallbackReason dwCallbackReason, IntPtr hSourceFile, IntPtr hDestinationFile, IntPtr lpData);
    #endregion


    #region Fields
    private int isCancelled;
    private int filePercentCompleted;
    private static bool finished = true;
    private static bool errorOccurred;
    private static License license;
    #endregion


    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the flag indicating that copying has finished.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool Finished => finished;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the flag indicating that an error occurred while copying.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool ErrorOccurred => errorOccurred;
    #endregion


    #region Event Handlers
    private event EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs> ProgressChanged;
    #endregion


    #region Enumerations
    /// <summary>
    /// Progress result.
    /// </summary>
    private enum CopyProgressResult : uint
    {
        PROGRESS_CONTINUE = 0
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Callback reason.
    /// </summary>
    private enum CopyProgressCallbackReason : uint
    {
        CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED = 0x00000000
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// File flags.
    /// </summary>
    [Flags]
    private enum CopyFileFlags : uint
    {
        COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS = 0x00000001,
        COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING = 0x00001000,
        COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE = 0x00000002
    }
    #endregion


    #region Constructors
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor that is internal.
    /// </summary>
    private XCopy()
    {
        license = LicenseManager.Validate(typeof(XCopy), this);
        isCancelled = 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor.
    /// </summary>
    static XCopy()
    {
        license = LicenseManager.Validate(typeof(XCopy), IntPtr.Zero);
    }
    #endregion


    #region Internal Members
    /// <summary>
    /// Copy source file to destination.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="destination"></param>
    /// <param name="overwrite"></param>
    /// <param name="nobuffering"></param>
    /// <param name="handler"></param>
    private void CopyInternal(string source, string destination, bool overwrite, bool nobuffering, EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs> handler)
    {
        errorOccurred = false;
        finished = false;

        try
        {
            var copyFileFlags = CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE;

            if (!overwrite)
            {
                copyFileFlags |= CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS;
            }

            if (nobuffering)
            {
                copyFileFlags |= CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING;
            }

            if (handler != null)
            {
                ProgressChanged += handler;
            }

            var result = CopyFileEx(source, destination, CopyProgressHandler, IntPtr.Zero, ref isCancelled, copyFileFlags);

            if (!result)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogManager.Log(LogType.ERROR, "Copy: " + e.Message);

            if (handler != null)
            {
                ProgressChanged -= handler;
                errorOccurred = true;
            }

            finished = true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Progress handler.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="total"></param>
    /// <param name="transferred"></param>
    /// <param name="streamSize"></param>
    /// <param name="streamByteTrans"></param>
    /// <param name="dwStreamNumber"></param>
    /// <param name="reason"></param>
    /// <param name="hSourceFile"></param>
    /// <param name="hDestinationFile"></param>
    /// <param name="lpData"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private CopyProgressResult CopyProgressHandler(long total, long transferred, long streamSize, long streamByteTrans, uint dwStreamNumber, 
        CopyProgressCallbackReason reason, IntPtr hSourceFile, IntPtr hDestinationFile, IntPtr lpData)
    {
        if (reason == CopyProgressCallbackReason.CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED)
        {
            OnProgressChanged((transferred / (double)total) * 100.0);
        }

        if (transferred >= total)
        {
            finished = true;
        }

        return CopyProgressResult.PROGRESS_CONTINUE;
    }
    #endregion


    #region External Members
    /// <summary>
    /// Copy using an overwrite and buffer flag.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="destination"></param>
    /// <param name="overwrite"></param>
    /// <param name="nobuffering"></param>
    public static void Copy(string source, string destination, bool overwrite, bool nobuffering)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                new XCopy().CopyInternal(source, destination, overwrite, nobuffering, null);
            }
            catch (AggregateException e)
            {
                foreach (var error in e.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    LogManager.Log(LogType.DEBUG, error.Message);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Copy using an overwrite and buffer flag along with a progress event handler.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="destination"></param>
    /// <param name="overwrite"></param>
    /// <param name="nobuffering"></param>
    /// <param name="handler"></param>
    public static void Copy(string source, string destination, bool overwrite, bool nobuffering, EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs> handler)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                new XCopy().CopyInternal(source, destination, overwrite, nobuffering, handler);
            }
            catch (AggregateException e)
            {
                foreach (var error in e.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    LogManager.Log(LogType.DEBUG, error.Message);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dispose of the license.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (license != null)
        {
            license.Dispose();
            license = null;
        }
    }
    #endregion


    #region Events
    /// <summary>
    /// Handle changing progress.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="percent"></param>
    private void OnProgressChanged(double percent)
    {
        if ((int)percent > filePercentCompleted)
        {
            filePercentCompleted = (int)percent;
            ProgressChanged?.Invoke(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs(filePercentCompleted, null));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Zero byte files will probably throw an exception here `(transferred / (double)total)`  (assuming the callback gets called).

Comment: Zero byte files won't enter this routine, it's checked outside this scope. My files have a size to them. Routine is called, even when the problem occurs, 100% with 1GB or more files, but no metadata to go along with the file.

Comment: "delayed write failure" So you have turned on write caching and ripping the USB stick out, right?

Comment: @usr After the copy is 100% I ripped the USB out thinking the copy is complete, but it is still writing metadata which I'm trying to work around. So, 100% is not accurate.